# Can you create methods in the same style as attributes?

Tags: c#

Let's say i want to make a method e.g.

```
public static void CreateMenu(float x, float y, float w, float h, string header)
{
 //code here
}
```

but i want to make it so people can put the parameters in any order, but instead of making a bunch of methods allowing this, is there a way i could make it like a attribute and have parameters be properties, e.g.

```
public static void CreateMenu(Properties: Xpos = float, Ypos = float, Width = float, Header = float, Header = string)
{
 //code here
}
```

or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They already can:

```
YourType.CreateMenu(y: 12, w: 4, header: "abc", x: 1, h: 0);
```

But no: nothing additional is available, unless you change the API to accept a single parameter object/value with members that are assigned by the caller, i.e.

```
YourType.CreateMenu(new MenuArgs {
    Y = 12, W = 4,
    Header = "abc",
    X = 1, H = 0
});
```

Comment: oh, is that a thing you can do? Didnt know, I thought you were only allowed to input in the the specific order `CreateMenu(0, 0, 100, 250, "Hello World");`

Comment: Since c# 4: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments